# Unloading a JavaAgent

Tags: java, jvm, profiler, javaagents

Using [Java Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html) I have been able to load my java agent (e.g. jar file) into my target program.

Below is my code.

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.*;

String javaAgentPath = "C:\\agent\\jAgent.jar"; 
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(PID);

vm.loadAgent(javaAgentPath, null);
```

Attaching to a running JVM and loading my agent jar file is working well.
Now I want to unload my agent jarfile, but Attach API doesn't provide `unloadAgent()` method.

Is there any way to unload my javaagent file?

Answer (score 0):

`vm.detatch()` is what you're looking for